# Concatenate results of two queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union, android-room

Table 1 :Selected persons

```
id|name|date|rating
```

Table 2 :Persons

```
id|name|date|rating
```

I want to build a query which will return all the selected persons  order by date desc from `table 1` and all persons from `table 2` order by rating in desc order.

if there are 3 persons in table 1 and 4 persons in table 2, the query should return first 3 selected persons ordered by date as first 3 entries and then 4 persons entries with order by rating.
How can I achieve this using sql?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method that will work in most databases:

```
select id, name, date, rating
from ((select id, name, date, rating, 1 as which
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select id, name, date, rating, 2 as which
       from table1
      )
     ) t
order by which,
         (case when which = 1 then date end),
         rating
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want:

```
select id, name, date, rating
from (
    select id, name, date, rating, 't1' which from table1
    union all
    select id, name, date, rating, 't2' which from table2
)
order by
    case when which = 't1' then date end desc,
    rating end desc
```

The subquery uses `union all` to select from both tables, with an additional column that indicates from which table each record comes from. Then, the outer query does a conditional sort:

- the `case` expression returns the `date` of coming from `t1`, else `null`; the descending sort hence puts `t1  rows first, ordered by descending dates (rows from`t2`get`null`, which, in descending order, comes last)
- the second sort criteria sorts the remaining rows (ie those from `t2  by descending`rating`

In MySQL, this can be shortened a little:

```
(
    select id, name, date, rating, 't1' which from table1
    union all
    select id, name, date, rating, 't2' which from table2
)
order by
    case when which = 't1' then date end desc,
    rating end desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a use case for Union. Try the following query:

```
SELECT id, name, date, rating FROM table1   
ORDER BY date DESC
UNION
SELECT id, name, date, rating FROM table2
ORDER BY rating DESC
```